# Detect connection is encrypted (or not)

Tags: node.js, encryption, https, pem

I've just tested this HTTPS server I found on the official node.js site:

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const options = {
  "key": fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
  "cert": fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
};

server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.write("Hello!");
  res.end();
});

server.listen(8000);
```

I created the two **self-signed** certificate files with openssl:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out cert.pem
```

It runs fine, I can connect with a browser and get a certificate warning (because it is self-signed) and click-trhough to accept the page nonetheless.

> What I need is not client or server authentication, **just encryption**!

I will not connect to the server with a browser, this is just the very beginning of a longer project and there will be a custom client who knows that the server is not authenticated and ignore this shortcoming.

My qualms are about the encryption. Is there a way to tell **server-side**, if the connection has been actually successfully encrypted? Or, detect if the connection has **not been encrypted** as *promised*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default cipher suites configuration](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_modifying_the_default_tls_cipher_suite) supports only cipher suites that provide strong encryption. It means that if a connection has been established, the encryption of the chosen cipher suite will be applied.

However, you should force the use of TLS 1.2 in order to prevent protocol downgrade attacks through the [options](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options):

```
const options = {
  "key": fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
  "cert": fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
  "secureProtocol": "TLSv1_2_method"
};
```

Comment: Sadly, I also work with mono on linux. With `"secureProtocol": "TLSv1_2_method"` downgrades to `TLSv1/SSLv3` are not allowed. I understand this helps against vulnerabilities. But they are mostly bound to server authentication, which I don't use anyways. The mono client won't connect out of the box because it does not support `TLSv1.2`. Is a downgrade to `AES256-SHA version TLSv1/SSLv3` even relevant to encryption? I'm only interested in avoiding packet spoofing from intercepting credentials. Is it that bad if I omit the line and permit a downgrade?

Comment: A `protocol downgrade attack` wouldn't affect the server. The only critical payload is the SHA256 password pre-hash being sent to the server. An attacker would just be able to read the response (`CRED`, meaning credentials error) in **his own (!)** packets, but nothing more from the server. A may be totally wrong but I have the impression that the vulnerabilities are relevant to the web, where users may follow links to impostor websites showing forged certificates. But if there are no links? No certificates to exhibit? Just packets to shield from eavesdropping? ...please enlighten me :)

Comment: You're safe if you assume that an attacker is passive (can only observe packets). If an attacker is active (can drop and manipulate packets), then they may downgrade the TLS 1.0 connection to SSLv3 connection and use further attacks to decrypt observed ciphertexts through either padding-based attacks (for CBC modes) or many-time pads (RC4).